# Setting the Type of a Struct Constructor in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a matrix data type in Rust that supports a generic element data type.

```rust
pub struct Matrix<T> {
    data: Vec<T>,  // row-major storage
    nrows: usize,
    ncols: usize,
}
```

I would like to create a family of different matrix constructors such as `zero` and `eye` which output the zero matrix and the identity matrix, respectively. A standard `Matrix::new()` constructor is straightforward:

```rust
impl<T> Matrix<T> {
    pub fn new(data: Vec<T>, nrows: usize, ncols: usize) -> Matrix<T> {
        assert!(data.len() == nrows*ncols);

        Matrix { data: data, nrows: nrows, ncols: ncols }
    }
}
```

The underlying type `T` is inferred from the type of the initializing vector. However, when I try to write a `Matrix::zero()` constructor I run into issues figuring out how to infer the type since the only parameters I want to pass is the size.

```rust
impl<T> Matrix<T> {
    pub fn zero(nrows: usize, ncols: usize) -> Matrix<T>
    where T : Clone
    {
        let data: Vec<T> = vec![0; nrows*ncols];
        Matrix::new(data, nrows, ncols)
    }
}
```

Trying to compile this results in the error message:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types                                                                                                                
  --> src/tools.rs:39:33                                                                                                                      
   |                                                                                                                                          
39 |         let data: Vec<T> = vec![0; nrows*ncols];                                                                                         
   |                                 ^ expected type parameter, found integral variable                                                       
   |                                                                                                                                          
   = note: expected type `T`                                                                                                                  
              found type `{integer}`
```

I tried `0 as T` and `T::from(0)` and those don't resolve the issue. (To be honest, I don't yet understand why.) One possible solution is to change the function definition to `zero(_value: T, nrows: usize, ncols: usize)` and construct the data vector via `vec![_value; ...]` but that seems odd.

Whatever the solution my end goal is to be able to simply write,

```rust
let a: Matrix<f32> = Matrix::zero(nrows, ncols);
// ... or ...
let b = Matrix<f32>::zero(nrows, ncols);
// ... or ...
let c = Matrix::zero<f32>(nrows, ncols);
// ... or something else?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use the [num](https://crates.io/crates/num) crate, which adds traits for situations like this.

Something like:

```
extern crate num;
use num::Zero;

impl<T> Matrix<T> {
    pub fn zero(nrows: usize, ncols: usize) -> Matrix<T>
    where T : Clone + Zero
    {
        let data: Vec<T> = vec![T::zero(); nrows*ncols];
        Matrix::new(data, nrows, ncols)
    }
}
```

would probably work, because it defines your matrix type as bounded by types that implement the `num::Zero` trait. This is implemented over all integer and floating-point primitives, and can be implemented for custom types as well.

If you don't want to import the `num` crate, you can define this trait manually like below, though it will require you to implement it for primitives yourself.

```
trait Zero {
    fn zero() -> Self;
}
impl Zero for f32 {
    fn zero() -> Self {
        0.0
    }
}
...
```

Comment: I like the Zero trait approach, even though it is verbose. I’ll also check out the num package to see what that’s all about. Waiting for another possible answer before I give you the “Answered Question”. :)